# Editing element of Data.Map haskell

Tags: haskell

I have got a map `(Map (Int,Int) Int)` (call it `Mapp`). I want to create a function `mod :: Mapp -> [(Int,Int,Int)] -> Mapp` which for every triple (a,b,c) of given list sets `Mapp[(a,b)] = c`. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
mod = foldr (\(a, b, c) -> Map.insert (a, b) c)
```

The idea is really simple: we can insert elements from the list one by one using the `fold` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

mod :: (Ord k0, Ord k1) => M.Map (k0, k1) a -> [(k0, k1, a)] -> M.Map (k0, k1) a
mod m l = M.fromList (map (\(a,b,c) -> ((a,b),c)) l) `M.union` m
```

Explained: take your list `l` of triples `(a,b,c)` and change those into `((a,b),c)`.

```
map (\(a,b,c) -> ((a,b),c)) l
```

With the new list, make a new map.

```
M.fromList (map (\(a,b,c) -> ((a,b),c)) l)
```

Then use `M.union` to union the new map above and the old one `m`:

```
M.fromList (map (\(a,b,c) -> ((a,b),c)) l) `M.union` m
```

Since `M.union` is left-biased, the associations in the left map have higher precedence over the ones in the right map, effectively replacing the old values with the new ones.